# SQL Connection Error Message

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm trying to log an error message to a database when an exception is thrown. The idea is to have the exception be logged into the database so it can be investigated at a later time.

This is the code:

```
private void btnGroundMVC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    try
            {
                Process.Start(Library.paiplib.GroundMVC);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                String timeStamp = Library.staticlib.getTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(errorlog, sqlconn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeStamp", timeStamp);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex", ex);

                sqlconn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconn.Close();

                MessageBox.Show(Library.paiplib.error + ex,"Error Loading PAIP", MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);

            }
```

This is the error message while debugging:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No mapping exists from object type
>   System.ArgumentException to a known managed provider native type."

This says that is at the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: the SQL Server provider doesn't know of an `Exception`-compatible column type.

If you'll simply want to store the string representation of the exception:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex", ex.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you @CodeCaster. Converting it to a string worked.

Answer (score -1):

i would use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ex", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value
```

Comment: the error is with the datatype which the op is not specifying. declaring the correct type will eliminate this